# When should I use HDL or visual tools?

Tags: simulation, hdl

I am a kind of software man, and I decided to learn how the computer works under the hood. So I have read a few computer architecture books, and now I have a decent understanding about how digital circuits work (at logic gates level). I want to design and build an 8-bit computer with a 16 bit address bus. I wanted to build it in a PCB with 74 series ICs, except RAM and ROM chips. 
I have been using a visual digital circuit simulator called [LogicCircuit](http://www.logiccircuit.org/).
But while designing the ALU I have encountered the problem of testing, I cannot test that every works properly, I can only test it manully, but I wanted to have some kind of Unit Testing that I can program and run. For that purpose I discovered HDL (Hardware Description Language). But all the tutorials I have seen show how to build functionality coding and then a synthesizer compiled it to logic gates, so I think I wouldn't learn that much.
 (1) Should I design everything first visually and then port every logic gate to HDL and test it? 
(2) Do I simply have a misconception about what is HDL? 
 (3) Do you know a visual digital circuit simulator which supports testing (maybe a scripting language)? 
(4) Should I simply do everything in HDL? 
 (5) When should I use HDL and when should I use visual tools?

By the way, currently I am using Autodesk Eagle to build the PCB.
Thanks, Pedro

Comment: For logic design HDL is the only tool which is used in the industry, since it is just not feasible to "draw" any somewhat serious project, as it will contain thousands to millions of gates. The visual tools are good for some top-level block-diagram schematics, for learning and for presentations.

Comment: In college, when we built an 8bit mips microprocessor, we had to build it visually over the course of a quarter. The next class, we started learning HDL and created the entire microprocessor with 16 lines of code within one week (vs 10 for the previous visual course). While anything can be done visually, the power of HDL should not be understated.

Comment: And another important point: formal verification works best with a formally described stuff (which schematic is not).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Do you think that if I build the whole computer with HDL without having ever made any other complex circuit with visual design I will learn enough? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you realize that HDL development will not produce a design based on 74xx chips. Bascially, the result will be something you load in a single CPLD/FPGA chip that will do what a lot of 74xx chips would do. But you'll learn a lot more with HDL than you would with 74xx chips.

Comment: One advantage of the HDL approach is you have a full programming language available to automate testing and perform regression tests, asserting when any outputs aren't as expected - you only need visuals as an aid to exploring what went wrong

Comment: @PedroPalacios Well, when you are building something with HDL you should clearly picture in your mind how it should look in the schematics. If you don't - you won't build anything good. As I said, schematics are good for understanding and learning.

Comment: These days, using 74XX IMHO is a huge waste of time. With a small FPGA you can, in a matter of minutes, experiment with different configuration of ALUs, pipeline, processor register width and countless other options that would take months if not years to rewire using discrete chips.

Comment: So I posted an answer, but after thinking about it, I think your question is a bit too broad and a little ambiguous. Each one of your sub questions could be a post on its own and your main question is really comparing two things not in the same category. Visual tools can be used to help design a system in either HDL or 7400 series logic. HDL isn't so much a visual tool and more of a programming language for hardware designers. I would repost your question and specifically ask about how to design and test a 7400 series custom CPU.

Comment: @JakeRobinson Sorry, I am new to stack exchange. How should I repost it? I don't want to create too many questions. Thanks

Comment: Beside tutorials, you should download a few open source HDL projects and see how things work together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to build with 7400 series parts, then you may be better off directly designing with 7400 series parts and drawing up a schematic.  However, it is possible to design in HDL and synthesize for 7400 series logic.  The open source synthesis software yosys can actually target 7400 series logic for synthesis.  It may end up being a gigantic pain to wire up and debug for a complex design, but it is possible.

I think it really depends on what it is that you want to learn.  If you want to learn modern hardware design, then out with the 7400 logic.  Get a reasonable FPGA dev board and work in Verilog or VHDL.  And FYI, modern hardware design is not done at the gate level, it's generally done at the behavioral level with conditionals, register transfer operations, state machines, etc.  The synthesis software then turns that high-level design into optimized logic that that targets your target device/process.  If you want to build something out of 7400 series logic 'just because', then work at a schematic level and design directly with 7400 series parts.  You can certainly write gate-level HDL (for most things, anyway) to validate that your design will work.

Comment: Synthesizing for 7400 series logic? Didn't know there was tools able to do that. Funny. Certainly not very practical.